# exempt one module from maven enforcer plugin

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom, maven-enforcer-plugin

I have a multi module maven project.  Some of the modules require dependency `D`.  In order for things to work right, we need `compat` to come BEFORE `D` in the class path.  (Module `D` comes from maven central, whereas `compat` is one of the modules in our multi-module project.)  If `compat` comes after `D` or is omitted entirely, things seems to work, but actually don't.

Rather than trying to make everyone remember to always pull in both modules, I thought I'd do two things:

1. pull in `D` as part of `compat`.  This helps, but not much.  Now people still remember to avoid `D` and use `compat` instead.  But at least the pom.xml file is a bit more concise.
2. Use the maven enforcer plugin to ban `D`.  Then if someone forgets, the build fails and they get a reminder.

The problem with part 2 is that the `compat` module itself needs to import `D`.  So I need to make an exception for it.  Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Do you need to use maven-enforcer-plugin for anything else in the compat module, or would disabling it entirely be acceptable?

Comment: that would be fine

Comment: I’ll try to write a more comprehensive answer later, but try adding the property [`<enforcer.skip>true</enforcer.skip>`](https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/maven-enforcer-plugin/enforce-mojo.html#skip) in just the compat project POM.

Comment: Oh, wow, nice!  And there's even options to skip specific rules!